# Rails Acts_as_votable Average Bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

I am using acts_as_votable in my rails app

Users can Like and Dislike an Article
TO display likes and dislikes I use these codes

```
 <%= @article.votes.size %>
(<%= @article.upvotes.size %> Likes)
(<%= @article.downvotes.size %> Dislikes)
```

But say i want to sum it up?

How can I show an average of ALL votes using 5 Stars?
Or even better, using a Ratings Bar like Youtube Has?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you want simple youtube like bar then use the following:

```
<div style="background-color:#ccc;width:200px;">
  <div style="background-color:#f00;height:30px;width:<%= (@article.upvotes.size/@article.votes.size)* 100 %>%;">
  </div>
  <i style="float:left"> Like: <%= @article.upvotes.size%> </i><i style="float:right"> Dislike: <%= @article.downvotes.size%> </i>
</div>
```

You can try with: [ajaxful-rating](https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating). I am using it in my project.

Comment: Yes but what is the code that would be used to highlight the correct stars

Comment: everything is in the document. Sample usage to display to ratings:

#show.html.erb
`<%= ratings_for @article %>`

#To display static stars:
`<%= ratings_for @article, :static %>`
etc.

Comment: But i've already got a voting system set up and fully functional. 

Wont the code provided and the Ajaxful-Rating gem run into some problems with my Acts_as_votable system

Comment: no problem. just go through the `ratings_for` helper method of ajaxful-rating gem. You will get clear idea about how to implement average rating

Comment: For some reason adding Ajaxful ratings to my app causes massive amount of errors 

Do you not have any other resources? Like a youtube like bar?

Comment: you dont need to use Ajaxful ratings to your app as you already have a solution working, what I suggest is to create a helper method like `ratings_for` of Ajaxful ratings. I believe it wont create any complexity

Comment: I'm new to rails, how would i go by doing this?

Comment: In responsive to your edit, made on  Jun 29 at 18:33

This Doesnt work because, say there are 3 Likes and 1 Dislike, it will show only the grey bar, whereas if there are 4 Likes and 0 Dislikes it will show only the red bar